# How to deal with long formula?

Tags: support, mathjax

How to show a formula too long to fit in a line?

For example:
$$ P(Y-X=m | Y > X) = \sum_{k} P(Y-X=m, X=k | Y > X) = \sum_{k}  P(Y-X=m | X=k, Y > X) P(X=k | Y > X) = \sum_{k}  P(Y-k=m | Y > k) P(X=k | Y > X).$$

Thanks!

Comment: Why downvote this?

Comment: @Moron: Some people are just pathetic...

Comment: Let us not jump to conclusions. Perhaps they think they have a valid reason? I am guessing one possible reason could be that it is already in the FAQ (although my brief search didn't bring up any). The downvote could be to encourage searching the FAQ first. Of course, downvoting without commenting is pointless in that case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use double dollars and the \begin{align*} environment (within TeX-mode) to solve the problem.

$$\begin{align*}  
P(Y-X=m | Y > X) &= \sum_{k} P(Y-X=m, X=k | Y > X) \\
&= \sum_{k}  P(Y-X=m | X=k, Y > X) P(X=k | Y > X) \\
&= \sum_{k}  P(Y-k=m | Y > k) P(X=k | Y > X).\end{align*}$$

`$$\begin{align*}

P(Y-X=m | Y > X) &= \sum_{k} P(Y-X=m, X=k | Y > X) \
&= \sum_{k}  P(Y-X=m | X=k, Y > X) P(X=k | Y > X) \
&= \sum_{k}  P(Y-k=m | Y > k) P(X=k | Y > X).\end{align*}$$`

Comment: What about a case where one has a single long formula which begins with a `\left(`and ends with a `\right)`? The `align` environment seems to fail (in MathJax) for that case.

Comment: @Eric: You can use the invisible `\right.` to close the `left(` on the first line and the invisible `\left.` to open the closing `\right)` on the last line and make `\begin{align}...\end{align}` happy.

Comment: Actually, the `\begin{align*}` environment can be used without first going into TeX mode (without the double dollar signs), though it sometimes requires you to escape with extra backslashes to get the interpreter to understand.

Comment: @Eric: the specific problem with `\left` and `\right` pairs not working across line breaks is also inherent already in standard TeX, so not a problem with MathJax per se. The usual way to solve the problem is to manually insert `\big` and similar versions. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula

Comment: @Isaac: But that can give problems because the left bracket and the right bracket don't have to be of the same size!

Comment: One way to get them to be the same size is using the vphantom command.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know Isaac's trick. How cool.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What is the difference between `\begin{align*}` and `\begin{align}`?

Comment: @Aðøbe: On this site? None. In general? `align*` is an unnumbered environment, whereas `align` is numbered.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, since MathJax supports the `amsmath` extensions, the `split` environment is also supported:

$$\begin{split}P(Y-X=m | Y > X) &= \sum_{k} P(Y-X=m, X=k | Y > X) \\ &= \sum_{k} P(Y-X=m | X=k, Y > X) P(X=k | Y > X) \\ &= \sum_{k} P(Y-k=m | Y > k) P(X=k | Y > X).\end{split}$$

which is generated by

`$$\begin{split}
P(Y-X=m | Y > X) &= \sum_{k} P(Y-X=m, X=k | Y > X) \\ &= \sum_{k} P(Y-X=m | X=k, Y > X) P(X=k | Y > X) \\ &= \sum_{k} P(Y-k=m | Y > k) P(X=k | Y > X).\end{split}$$`

Comment: And nobody pointed out that it would be *much nicer* to use `\mid` instead of `|`... :)

Comment: @Theo: ROFL, yes. :D It sucks MathJax doesn't support the `\middle` to go along with `\left` and `\right` though.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that... Hmm. That's probably because I normally use colons for that purpose.

Answer (score 5):

As the last mathematician in the world still using Plain TeX, I'd do it with eqalign.

$$\eqalign{P(Y-X=m\mid Y\gt X)&=\sum_kP(Y-X=m,X=k\mid Y\gt X)\cr&=\sum_kP(Y-X=m\mid X=k,Y\gt X)\,P(X=k\mid Y>X)\cr&=\sum_kP(Y-k=m\mid Y\gt k)\,P(X=k\mid Y\gt X)\cr}$$

```
\eqalign{
  P(Y-X=m\mid Y\gt X)
    &=\sum_kP(Y-X=m,X=k\mid Y\gt X)\cr
    &=\sum_kP(Y-X=m\mid X=k,Y\gt X)\,P(X=k\mid Y>X)\cr
    &=\sum_kP(Y-k=m\mid Y\gt k)\,P(X=k\mid Y\gt X)\cr
}
```

Comment: "last mathematician in the world still using Plain $\TeX$" - IIRC, Arturo's another one, so I'm not sure about that claim... :)

Comment: Thanks, Theo; thanks, J. M., I'm in good company then.